# Bill Of Materials and CTE (MariaDB)

Tags: mariadb, common-table-expression

this is my first time here for my question, therefore I hope it will be clear enought to get an answer.

I have collections and need to create a relationship between them. Each of the collection should be a child of any other collection (with its childs).

Example of defined relations (with IDs) are below:

```
2
|-3
|-4

5
|-3

4
|-5
```

Now when retreiving a tree for collection 2 I need to get (expecting):

```
2
|-3
|-4
  |-5
    |-3
```

However getting:

```
2
|-3
|-4
  |-5
```

Testing table:

```
CREATE TABLE collection_bom (
    id INT,
    collection_id varchar(20),
    reference_id varchar(20)
);

-- definition 2-3-4 relationship
INSERT INTO collection_bom(id,collection_id,reference_id) VALUES (1,2,NULL);
INSERT INTO collection_bom(id,collection_id,reference_id) VALUES (2,3,1);
INSERT INTO collection_bom(id,collection_id,reference_id) VALUES (3,4,2);
-- definition of 5-3 relationship
INSERT INTO collection_bom(id,collection_id,reference_id) VALUES (4,5,NULL);
INSERT INTO collection_bom(id,collection_id,reference_id) VALUES (5,3,4);
-- definition of 4-5 relationship
INSERT INTO collection_bom(id,collection_id,reference_id) VALUES (6,5,3);
```

Query:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select t.*
      from collection_bom t
      where reference_id IS NULL AND collection_id = 2
      union all
      select t.*
      from cte join
           collection_bom t
           on cte.id = t.reference_id
     )
select *
from cte;
```

```
Result:
id  collection_id   reference_id
1   2               null
2   3               1
3   4               2
6   5               3
```

In the result I need to have collection_id 3 as a child of 5 as well.

Now I am realising that it might not be a good approach.
Any help appreciated!

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u3MyizdSwWaVEMa9XfiXUw/0)

Answer (score 0):

You have a semantical issue in the insert section; The definition of the 5-3 relationship starts a new tree from scratch (with NULL reference), that is independent from your original tree. Therefore the "5" that you define in this 2nd tree is different from the other "5" in the 1st tree.
In the definition of the 4-5 relationship you don't use the NULL reference, you link it to a reference in the 1st table, hence it works well.

This insert section can do what you want:

```
-- definition 2-3-4 relationship
INSERT INTO collection_bom(id,collection_id,reference_id) VALUES (1,2,NULL);
INSERT INTO collection_bom(id,collection_id,reference_id) VALUES (2,3,1);
INSERT INTO collection_bom(id,collection_id,reference_id) VALUES (3,4,1);
-- definition of 4-5 relationship
INSERT INTO collection_bom(id,collection_id,reference_id) VALUES (4,5,3);
-- definition of 5-3 relationship
-- INSERT INTO collection_bom(id,collection_id,reference_id) VALUES (4,5,NULL);
INSERT INTO collection_bom(id,collection_id,reference_id) VALUES (5,3,4);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that. So it is neccessary to register every each relationship into the table.
If I create 6-7 relationship and want to attach another 5-3 branch to 7 (while keeping 4-5-3 relationship), I have to define 7-5-3 relationship again. Does any other tool suitable for this task exist?